# Meters to feet and inches

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert meters to feet & inches.

The kick is getting the meter to split properly into feet and inches of course.

example 1.78 should equal F 5 IN 10

```
    meters = 0.3048 * feet;

    centimeters = 2.54 * inches;

or 

const double METERS_PER_FOOT = 0.3048;

const double INCHES_PER_FOOT = 12.0;
```

I have the skeleton

```
cout << "How tall are you in meters? \n";

cin >> meters;


cout << "You're this tall in feet and inches F" << feet << " IN" << inches "\n";
```

I how no clue on how to setup the formulas to get the split right.

I can't use cMath or this conversion thing I've seen on other examples.

Comment: if you can't use cMath perhaps you can just use math instead?

Comment: Convert meters to inches, then convert inches to feet + inches. You know how to do that, right?

Comment: This is simple math, and doesn't require `cMath` or any "conversion thing". If you were to do it with pencil and paper, how would you do so?

Comment: @KenWhite. If the OP had an answer to that, we wouldn't be reading this.

Comment: It's been a while, but you should select an answer here...

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a math problem than a programming problem. Given a length in feet, which is trivial to get from meters, you need to convert the fractional part of the feet to inches. You can do this with integer casting and modulo operations:

```
const double METERS_PER_FOOT = 0.3048;
const double INCHES_PER_FOOT = 12.0;
double heightInMeters = 1.78;
double heightInFeet = heightInMeters / METERS_PER_FOOT;
int feet = (int)heightInFeet;
int inches = (int)((heightInFeet - feet) * INCHES_PER_FOOT + 0.5);
```

The last step takes the fractional part `(heightInFeet - feet)`, multiplies it by the number of inches in a foot to get the number of inches, then rounds it by adding half and truncating to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>       /* floor */

double myLength = 1.88;
double feet = floor(myLength / 0.3048);
myLength -= feet * 0.3048;
double inches = floor(myLength / 0.0254);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work better.Its simpler i guess . It  takes input as meters and centimeters and then outputs as feets and inches. Its initially converts all reading into meters and then convert metrs to feet and inches.

```
float cms,metr;
metr+=cms/100;
float floatFeet = metr* 3.28084;
int feet = (int)floatFeet;
int inches = (int)((floatFeet - feet) * 12.0 );

cout<<"the length is "<<feet<<"feet"<<inches<<"inch";
```

firstly it converts meter to feet in float. by second step`int feet=(int)floatFeet` it eliminates decimals. by third step it takes the decimal part and covert it to inches.

Comment: Same as accepted answer, only without constants and without rounding.